# Does Entity Framework code-first support table partition?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-core

I'm using Entity Framework Core 2.2 code-first to create tables. Assume one table will be large in future. I want the similar function like `PARTITION BY RANGE (last_updated_time)` in Postgresql. How can I create it in EF code first? I googled but found nothing. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this problem not very common? Nowadays, do people still use partition tables for huge table or there are other new ways to replace it? Thanks.

Comment: or is it a bad way to create huge table by using entity framework code first? If so, why the ef is so popular?